# Spark - scala - How to convert DataFrame to custom object?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is block code. In the code snippet I am reading multi line `json` and converting into `Emp` object.

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val filePath = Configuration.folderPath + "emp_unformatted.json"
    val sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("findEmp")

    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConfig)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
    val formattedJsonData = sqlContext.read.option("multiline", "true").json(filePath)
    val res = formattedJsonData.rdd.map(empParser)
    for (e <- res.take(2)) println(e.name + " " + e.company + " " + e.about)

  }

  case class Emp(name: String, company: String, email: String, address: String, about: String)

  def empParser(row: Row): Emp =
    {
      new Emp(row.getAs("name"), row.getAs("company"), row.getAs("email"), row.getAs("address"), row.getAs("about"))
    }
```

My question is the line "`formattedJsonData.rdd.map(empParser)`" approach is correct? I am converting to `RDD` of `Emp` Object.
1. is that right approach.
2. Suppose I have 1L, 1M records, in that case any performance isssue. 
3. have any better option to convert collection of emp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **`spark 2`**, You can use `dataset` which is also `type-safe` plus it provides performance benefits of DataFrames.

```
val df = sqlSession.read.option("multiline", "true").json(filePath)

import sqlSession.implicits._

val ds: Dataset[Emp] = df.as[Emp]
```

Comment: i am using spark 2. is it enough to do val ds: Dataset[Emp] = df.as[Emp]. how it will map. for example df have more columns. but in emp ,have limited one.

Comment: @LearnHadoop: The columns should be same with the datatype, this is the limitation with this approach

Comment: i couldn't find import sqlSession.implicits._ sqlSession is a class or any object ref.